# How to add special fomatting to first line in text document?

Tags: python, text, quotes

I need to format a text document like so (notice the quotes in the first item in the list):

> ```
> Input
> "C:/temp/image1.tif"
> C:/temp/image2.tif
> C:/temp/image3.tif
> ```

This is what I have so far:

```
images = ['C:/temp/image1.tif', 'C:/temp/image2.tif', 'C:/temp/image3.tif']

out = 'C:/out'

inputs = open(os.path.join(out, "List.txt"), "w")
inputs.write("Input\n")

for i,img in enumerate(images):          
     inputs.write("{0}/{1}\n".format(ws, img))

inputs.close()
```

However, this yields the following without the quotes around the first item

> ```
> Input
> C:/temp/image1.tif
> C:/temp/image2.tif
> C:/temp/image3.tif
> ```

How can I get the first item in the list (C:/temp/image1.tif) in quotes on the text document?

Comment: Variable `ws` is undefined.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you make `images` an iterator, then you could use `next` to peel off the first item, and then proceed with iterating through the rest of the items in `images` as before:

```
images = iter(['C:/temp/image1.tif', 'C:/temp/image2.tif', 'C:/temp/image3.tif'])

with open(os.path.join(out, "List.txt"), "w") as inputs:
    inputs.write("Input\n")
    inputs.write('"{0}"\n'.format(next(images)))
    for img in images:          
        inputs.write("{0}\n".format(img))
```

Note, however, that if you make `images` an iterator then  (unlike as in your original code), you will not be able to iterate through `images` again since looping once will consume the iterator.

(I've changed the string format `{0}/{1}` to `{0}` since the original format would insert a `/` which does not show up in your desired result. I've also removed the call to `enumerate`, since `i` is not used inside the loop.)

---

Alternatively, if you wish to preserve `images` as a list, you could use `images[0]` to get the first item, and iterate through `images[1:]` to handle the rest.

```
images = ['C:/temp/image1.tif', 'C:/temp/image2.tif', 'C:/temp/image3.tif']
out = 'C:/out'
with open(os.path.join(out, "List.txt"), "w") as inputs:
    inputs.write("Input\n")
    inputs.write('"{0}"\n'.format(images[0]))
    for img in images[1:]:          
        inputs.write("{0}\n".format(img))
```

---

By the way, it is usually preferable to use a [with-statement](http://effbot.org/zone/python-with-statement.htm) when opening a file. That way, the file handle is automatically closed for you when Python's flow of execution leaves the with-statement (and even if an exception occurs).

Comment: Great, I appreciate the in-depth discussion on the process--this really helps, thanks.

Answer (score 1):

You need to surround your text with another set of quotes:

```
images = ['C:/temp/image1.tif', 'C:/temp/image2.tif', 'C:/temp/image3.tif']

out = 'C:/out'

inputs = open(os.path.join(out, "List.txt"), "w")
inputs.write("Input\n")

for i,img in enumerate(images):
     if i == 0:
        inputs.write('"{1}"\n'.format(img))
     else:
        inputs.write('{1}\n'.format(img))

inputs.close()
```

Answer (score 1):

You have to handle the first line as a special case, then process the rest:

```
import os

images = ['C:/temp/image1.tif', 'C:/temp/image2.tif', 'C:/temp/image3.tif']
out = 'C:/out'

if not os.path.exists(out):
    os.makedirs(out)

with open(os.path.join(out, "List.txt"), "w") as inputs:
    inputs.write("Input\n")
    inputs.write('"{}"\n'.format(images[0]))
    for img in images[1:]:
        inputs.write('{}\n'.format(img))
```

Answer (score 0):

You have to check at which line you are before print the text.

```
images = ['C:/temp/image1.tif', 'C:/temp/image2.tif', 'C:/temp/image3.tif']

out = 'C:/out'

inputs = open(os.path.join(out, "List.txt"), "w")
inputs.write("Input\n")

for i,img in enumerate(images):
    if i != 0:          
       inputs.write("{0}/{1}\n".format(ws, img))
    else:
       inputs.write("\"{0}/{1}\"\n".format(ws, img))
inputs.close()
```

Comment: That is not the problem, look at my answer. The problem is that it is not surrounded with another set of quotes.